# PHP - Private class variables giving error: undefined variable

Tags: php, class, variables, private

I am getting the error "Undefined variable: interval in C:\wamp\www\DGC\classes\DateFilter.php"

Here is my code for the DateFilter class:

```
class DateFilter extends Filter
{
    //@param daysOld: how many days can be passed to be included in filter
    //Ex. If daysOld = 7, everything that is less than a week old is included
    private $interval;

    public function DateFilter($daysOld)
    {
        echo 'days old' . $daysOld .'</ br>';
        $interval = new DateInterval('P'.$daysOld.'D');
    }


    function test()
    {
        echo $interval->format("%d days old </br>");
        //echo 'bla';
    }

}
```

When I create a new instance of the DateFilter class and call test() it give me the error. I realize it means the variable hasn't been initialized, but I know that the constructor is being called because I put an echo statement in there and it was output.

I have also tried:
$this::$interval->format(...);
self::$interval->format(...);
but it didn't work.

I know this is probably an easy fix, sorry for the noob question. Can't believe this stumped me.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have to use `$this->interval` to access the member variable `interval` in PHP.  See [PHP: The Basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

```
class DateFilter extends Filter
{
    private $interval;    // this is correct.

    public function DateFilter($daysOld)
    {
        $this->interval = new DateInterval('P'.$daysOld.'D');   // fix this
    }

    function test()
    {
        echo $this->interval->format("%d days old </br>");     // and fix this
    }
}
```

Comment: echo $this->$interval->format("%d days old </br>");

Is also giving me this same error :/

Comment: remove the second dollar sign.  It's $this->interval

Comment: I've always find quite "strange" that PHP forces you to use `$this` to access object fields. Many other languages such as C# will not (if the variable has not the same name of a local one). Anyway the use of `this` is always a good practice, IMHO: it helps you to quick look at object properties and avoid confusion with local variables.

Comment: Definitely. Python has the same requirement (with 'self.' although 'self' is just a convention, and you have to actually provide a 'self' parameter in a function).  I don't mind, because it makes sure you know what you're actually referencing. Quite important in these dynamic languages when you can declare stuff all over the place.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am use to languages where the this is optional. Anyways, when I take away the 2nd dollar sign, I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: you need to use `$this->interval` *everywhere*. Including DateFilter constructor.  Right now you're just creating a local variable named `$interval` in your ctor.

Answer (score 4):

`$interval` is local to the function. `$this->interval` references your private property.

```php
class DateFilter extends Filter
{
    //@param daysOld: how many days can be passed to be included in filter
    //Ex. If daysOld = 7, everything that is less than a week old is included
    private $interval;

    public function DateFilter($daysOld)
    {
        echo 'days old' . $daysOld .'</ br>';
        $this->interval = new DateInterval('P'.$daysOld.'D');
    }


    function test()
    {
        echo $this->interval->format("%d days old </br>");
        //echo 'bla';
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect, that was the last piece of the puzzle I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
function test()
{
    echo $this->interval->format("%d days old </br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

trying

```
public var $interval;
```

and

```
echo $this->interval;
```